# Using formfield_overrides to change textarea size in admin.TabularInline Form in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

TextField size is overridden using formfield_overrides:

```
from django.forms import Textarea, TextInput 

formfield_overrides = {
    models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':2, 'cols':25})},
}
```

This works on the parent form TextFields. Any related child model rendered using admin.TabularInline still shows TextArea with default size.

Notes TextArea in the main Model and Inline related Model

[image: Notes TextArea in main Model and Inline related Model]

Is there a way to change TextArea size of TextField of model rendered using admin.TabularInline class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, just use the same code in the corresponding Inline class,

**Admin.py**

```
YourInline(admin.TabularInline):

    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':2, 'cols':25})},
    }    
          ...
```

Comment: Worked as desired. Also made me recall that there should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Comment: Yes. Worked as desired. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Ajay Since you're new, note that it is a good pratice to accept helpful answer to give closure to a question. You're not obligated to answer or upvote my answer in any way, but it is good pratices to do so on answer that helped you. Anyway, glad it helped !

Comment: I did it immediately after testing this and got the message that "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score". After I cross the number, I'll recheck mark if not appearing as accepted answer.

Comment: @Ajay Note that voting requires rep but not accepting answers. You accept an asnwer to your question by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

You could just assign your model as text fields

```
strategy_description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=250)
cost_driver_description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=250)
```

[image]